# Deallocate Azure VMSS based on tag and current powerstate

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-vm-scale-set

I am attempting to get a list of VMSS that have a specific tag and are still powered/allocated and then deallocate those VMSS.

I have not seen a property in `Get-AzVmss` that shows the allocation or power state of the VMSS.

I did however find if I dig in to the instances themselves I can get the powerstate of them using `Get-AzVmssVM`

I am able to successfully get this to occur at the instance level and power the instances off, but I would like to deallocate the VMSS itself.

This will be part of a DevOps deployment pipeline so I need to ensure it's reliable and consistent. It will be run as an Azure Powershell Task.

Anyone able to assist in what I am missing here? I would love to do this a layer up and not even get in to the instances, but I could not see how to do that (assuming it is possible).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$RedTagValue = "Red"
$RGName = "test-rg"
$Resources = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $RGName | Where-Object { $_.Tags.Values -eq $RedTagValue }

foreach ($Resource in $Resources) {
    $vmss = Get-AzVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMScaleSetName $Resource.Name
    foreach ($vm in $vmss) {
        
        $instances = Get-AzVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMScaleSetName $Resource.Name -InstanceId $vm.InstanceId -InstanceView

        if ($instances.Statuses[1].Code -notcontains "PowerState/deallocated") {
            Write-Output "Turning off" #Need some code here to output the VMSS that are being turned off and also some logic to turn them off
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "No Machines to turn Off"
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stop-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMScaleSetName $Resource.Name -InstanceId $vm.InstanceId -Force
```

You need add the above `stop-azvmss` cmdlet in the `If` block in your script to stop a particular vmss instance.

Instead of Hardcoding the ResourcegroupName in your script, we have made some changes to it.

This new Script will validate the instance status whether are running or not. if instance are in running state then the script will trigger `stop-azvmss` cmdlets to deallocate those instance.

**Here is the Modified PowerShell Script :**

```
     $RedTagValue = "Red"
$Resources = Get-AzVmss| Where-Object { $_.Tags.Values -eq $RedTagValue }

foreach ($Resource in $Resources) {
    $vmss = Get-AzVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $Resources.ResourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $Resource.Name
    foreach($vm in $vmss){

        $instanceId=Get-AzVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $Resources.ResourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $Resource.Name -InstanceId $vm.InstanceId -InstanceView 
        if($instanceId.Statuses[1].Code -eq 'PowerState/running'){
            
            Write-Host "Turnning OFF","$($vm.Name)"

            Stop-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $Resources.ResourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $Resource.Name -InstanceId $vm.InstanceId -Force
}
        else {

        Write-Host "$($Resource.Name)","Virtual Machines are already turned off"
        }

    }
}
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do like the way you are getting the resource group there. I guess my question is does shutting off all of the instances within a VMSS also deallocate the VMSS itself? My end goal was wanting to deallocate the VMSS not only the instances of the VMSS.

Comment: Based on my Investigation , stopping all the instances will deallocate the VMSS itself.

Comment: I did some testing as well and it does seem to deallocate the VMSS, however it appears if you have any scale to specific instance count based autoscale resources attached those will still fire off. So i suppose I can use your method and also remove the autoscale resource from the VMSS in the same step and I believe that will serve my purposes. Thanks for the help